# Compactly supported function whose Fourier transform vanishes at infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Yes, I know that if $f$ is a function with compact support, then its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ cannot have compact support.
But are there conditions for which the function $\hat{f}$, being $f$ compactly supported, vanishes at infinity?
If so, what would those conditions be?

Comment: Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: It suffices that $f$ is absolutely integrable.